# How are ERC-721 protocol tokens different from Ardor assets? Is there a pro/con data sheet?

Tags: erc-721

ERC-721 protocol is used to create unique tokens like crypto kitties, but I'm curious has anyone compared it to the Ardor Ignis singleton assets as it seems like it does something similar. Is there a pro/cons data sheet?

Comment: Have a look at this recently published article by me, it doesn't provide a pro/con data sheet but some important points to consider: https://medium.com/@malnemark/erc721-non-fungible-tokens-and-ardor-singleton-assets-431a900e33ad